# Should someone mention her admission to other prestigous universities in past years when she applies for a PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, canada

Last year, one of my friends received a competitive PhD offer (including a full-time research assistant position) from a highly prestigious university in Canada, however her request for Study Visa was rejected because of some Social Tie issues.
This year, she has a plan to apply for universities in Europe and Australia. Is it worth mentioning her last year offer in her emails to the potential advisors or put it in her CV in order to increase her chance of acceptance?
Roughly speaking, the acceptance in the aforesaid Canadian university is considered harder than the European and Australian universities she wants to apply.

Comment: Related question: one of my friends wanted to ask a woman out on a date. She was nice looking but not stunning or anything. Should he mention to her when he asks her out that he previously dated a model?

Comment: @Rüdiger If it helps you to answer the question read it as "a bit prestigious" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just don't see that information as appropriate... it doesn't belong in a CV or the application. It could be appropriate for a letter of reference to mention it, though.

Comment: +1. If her application is good enough to have garnered an offer from such a prestigious institution, it will be good enough to attract further offers from other, less prestigious institutions.

Comment: @astronat, true. I'd intended to say that as well, but had to cut it short at the time.

Comment: You can still edit your answer and therefore improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The offer isn't CV worthy, but the CV gap and personal journey merit a mention somewhere, perhaps in a personal statement or a covering letter. (Maybe on a CV, if there's no other means.) For instance,

> *My PhD journey started over a year ago, when I applied and was accepted to [highly prestigious university], Canada. Unfortunately, my offer was eventually retracted due to visa issues.*

(The visa issues could be mentioned, if relevant.)

> *Exciting admission deadlines long gone, I spent the year [doing marvellous things], now I want to pursue [my original agenda].*