# Strengthening my CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

Does being accepted at great colleges but me rejecting to go to a better place hold any place in my CV, like

> Selected at this place in the department of that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should someone mention her admission to other prestigous universities in past years when she applies for a PhD program?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88076/should-someone-mention-her-admission-to-other-prestigous-universities-in-past-ye)

Comment: Who do you suppose should care about this? And which country?

Comment: India. I dont know I thought maybe it tells something about someone

Comment: @GoodDeeds: That question seems rather different, it concerns a student that received an offer but couldn't get a visa, which seems worthy of mentioning, since it explains a CV gap. (That student applied again next year.) The above question isn't so nuanced.

Comment: I vote to reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I rejected Stanford for Harvard*," doesn't hold much relevance (and won't impress anyone that graduated from Stanford)—**I suggest omitting such references**.

Comment: Late question but I think still relevant: How do lines like "Selected at Stanford for MS in Physics in 20XX" impact the reader of the resume in PhD admissions? I am asking this since it is _very_ common for some Indian students to write that they were selected here/there in the Scholastic Achievements section.